# I cannot run an example of JMS

Tags: java, jms

I'm trying to execute a simple Sender-Receiver example in using JMS.

I've written the code in eclipse, but when I do the lookup i receive this error:

*Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial*

Here you can find the code:

Receiver:

```
public class Receiver {
    static Context ictx = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ictx = new InitialContext();
        Queue queue = (Queue) ictx.lookup("queue");
        QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ictx.lookup("qcf");
        ictx.close();

        QueueConnection qc = qcf.createQueueConnection();
        QueueSession qs = qc.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        QueueReceiver qrec = qs.createReceiver(queue);
        TextMessage msg;
        qc.start();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            msg = (TextMessage) qrec.receive();
            System.out.println("Msg received: " + msg.getText());
        }

        qc.close();
    }
}
```

Sender:

```
public class Sender {
    static Context ictx = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ictx = new InitialContext();
        Queue queue = (Queue) ictx.lookup("queue");
        QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ictx.lookup("qcf");
        ictx.close();

        QueueConnection qc = qcf.createQueueConnection();
        QueueSession qs = qc.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        QueueSender qsend = qs.createSender(queue);
        TextMessage msg = qs.createTextMessage();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            msg.setText("Test number " + i);
            qsend.send(msg);
        }

        qc.close();
    }
}
```

Where's the mistake? Does I need to run it on a Server like glassfish?

Answer (score 0):

You would need an underlying implementation like Apache ActiveMQ, glassfish or any other JMS vendor. Depending on the product selected, the corresponding Jars and Queue need to be setup for the program to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using lookup to create resources like connectionfactory and queues. To use lookup, you need the jndi resources to be pre-configured.

If your intention is to just execute a simple producer-consumer(sender-receiver) jms example, you can have a look at this simple example that uses ActiveMQ as messaging broker: http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html